# Log4j - No mostrar paquetes en StackTrace de una excepción - Stack trace from hell

Tags: java, spring, log4j

Estoy utilizando log4j (v. 2.11.1) para generar los log de mi proyecto con Spring MVC y por tal motivo, al generarse una excepción, en el log se muestran todas las trazas correspondientes a Spring, las cuales desearía evitar (Tal como lo describen en este artículo: https://dzone.com/articles/filtering-stack-trace-hell ). Este mismo artículo ofrece soluciones al problema, pero la que más se acerca a lo que busco, está hecho para Logback, y yo utilizo log4j. He intentado buscar su equivalente en Log4j sin éxito.

Esta es la mejor alternativa que he encontrado y que quisiera replicar en log4j:

```
<pattern>
  %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5level | %thread | %logger{1} | %m%n%rEx{full,
      java.lang.reflect.Method,
      org.apache.catalina,
      org.springframework.aop
  }
</pattern>
```

Tras leer la documentación de Log4j agregué $ex{0}, luego de %m%n, pero eliminó por completo el stack trace, lo que tampoco deseo. He probado con filters y agregando el paquete con level=off en  sin éxito:

```
<logger name="org.springframework">
    <level value="off"/>
</logger>
```

Actualmente, esta es la forma en la que defino el contenido del log. Tengo 3 niveles, cada uno de los cuales va en un archivo diferente. Este es el ejemplo del nivel INFO:

```
<RollingFile name="InfoRollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/info.log"
filePattern="${log-path}/info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
<PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%level] - %c{1}: %m%n
    </pattern>
</PatternLayout>
<Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100MB" />
</Policies>
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
```

Tengo la sospecha que requerirá crear una clase que sobreescriba algún método de la librería de Log4j, pero no tengo claro como hacerlo. Toda guía, pista, ayuda, será bienvenida :) 
Gracias.

Comment: Hola revertir tu edición, pues la respuesta no debería ir en la misma pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que has llegado al lugar correcto de la documentación, pero de algún modo te has saltado una parte importante:

> **ex|exception|throwable**
>   ...  {filters(package,package,...)}
>
> Use `{filters(packages)}` where packages is a list of package names to suppress matching stack frames from stack traces.

Es decir, algo como

```
%ex{full}{ filters{ java.lang.reflect.Method, org.apache.catalina, org.springframework.aop}}
```

debería darte lo que buscas. Asegúrate de escribir bien el patrón, porque en la pregunta has usado `Ex` en lugar de `ex` y no estoy seguro de que se ignoren mayúsculas/minúsculas

Comment: Tu respuesta me ayudó a acercarme muchísimo a la solución. Repasé en la documentación y finalmente este cambio hizo el cambio que quise: `%xEx{filters(package1,package2)}`.